# How shall we deal with Question/Answer explicitly marked updates?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Consider situation where OP has updated question/answer, eg. due to comments or ambiguous answers.

Do we have any guidelines, how these q/a shall be formatted? Whether we allow responses to comments within q/a body ?

Also this relates to **suggested edits** review queue, as I've seen a lot of (for me) ambiguous suggests, where eg *Updates were moved from bottom to top of question/answer* or *q/a was entirely rewritten to merge all these updates* or *suggested edit, where change is added as part of answer but separated and annotated differently (eg. [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4691324))*

Few examples:

- [A semantics for Bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207168/a-semantics-for-bash-scripts)
- [Is the use of del bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331419/is-the-use-of-del-bad)
- [Shouldn't the code print " 1 1" instead of "4 4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323510/shouldnt-the-code-print-1-1-instead-of-4-4)
- [How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on/7848772#7848772)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4691324

Where sample q/a can look like this:

> **Question Title**
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sem non augue vehicula, ac condimentum lectus tristique. Donec in sapien quis nibh eleifend interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus eros nibh, molestie ac convallis iaculis, pulvinar sit amet magna. Ut tristique augue in nulla commodo tincidunt.
>
> **EDIT 1**
>   Nam ornare neque a quam rutrum cursus. Ut quis facilisis mauris. Cras vestibulum nulla aliquet, congue magna quis, volutpat turpis. Pellentesque vel elementum mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque tristique lobortis orci, vitae accumsan nulla semper eget.
>
> **EDIT 2**
>   Cras congue ipsum nec nunc mattis venenatis. Fusce quam nibh, lacinia vitae consectetur a, semper nec est. Sed quis turpis malesuada ligula sodales rhoncus at vitae arcu. Pellentesque pharetra ultrices mi eu porttitor. Praesent lacinia, felis ut condimentum scelerisque, justo orci pretium sem, at adipiscing tortor tellus sit amet mauris. Curabitur dignissim auctor augue, in interdum tortor luctus in.
>
> **RESPONSE FOR @USERNAME**
>   Maecenas ipsum lacus, pharetra vitae accumsan sit amet, hendrerit at leo. Vestibulum neque enim, iaculis non gravida non, ullamcorper eu arcu. Nam ut tortor mi. Nulla sollicitudin tellus vitae convallis malesuada. Vestibulum elementum lorem nec quam egestas, sit amet rutrum erat lacinia.
>
> **EDIT 3**
>   Suspendisse lacus est, aliquam eu mauris non, pharetra tristique dui. Phasellus in nulla non ligula pharetra tempus. Vestibulum nec lectus quis tellus congue semper. Pellentesque faucibus ipsum nisi, nec luctus nibh rutrum vel. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam pellentesque accumsan tempor. Nunc sed arcu eu felis hendrerit rutrum ut in dui. Praesent vulputate laoreet volutpat. Phasellus at gravida leo. Nunc euismod pellentesque massa, at blandit orci dictum nec.

Answer (score 3):

Merging the updates into a coherent question is a good thing.

We want questions and answers to be useful to future visitors, not just to the OP and people following the question in realtime. A future visitor shouldn't need to go through the OP's thought process in changing the question over time to get a good answer to the question they were googling when they found it.